# Properly render freestyle in this example?

Tags: rendering, eevee-render-engine, freestyle

I have a set of planes which I have "solidified" and then Boolean intersected with a skeletal hand to form the below model. The skeletal hand lines and the plane lines are in two different collections, which have two different freestyle line sets associated with them.

[image]

The planes have a black stlye, and the hand white. I have disabled selection by visibility and only have selection by collection enabled.

The render gives the following image: 
[image]

As you can see, all of the freestyle lines are overlapping one another, and it ruins the depth perception of the image. I cannot use visibility by QI range, because the same thing inevitably happens. Is there any way to stop this happening?